# Project Euler 54: Winning Poker Hand

Tags: python, beginner, programming-challenge, python-3.x, playing-cards

The problem can be found [here](https://projecteuler.net/problem=54).

> The file, poker.txt, contains one-thousand random hands dealt to two
>   players. Each line of the file contains ten cards (separated by a
>   single space): the first five are Player 1's cards and the last five
>   are Player 2's cards. You can assume that all hands are valid (no
>   invalid characters or repeated cards), each player's hand is in no
>   specific order, and in each hand there is a clear winner.
>
> How many hands does Player 1 win?

My code works good and solves the problem within 1.2 seconds. I'd like to improve the readability of my code however. Also, I think there are some better ways of comparing 2 hands in my function `def winninghand()`, but I do not know how. Furthermore, I feel like the way I sort the file may not be the most efficient/best/optimal.

```
import os
from collections import Counter
from time import time

cards = ['2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','T','J','Q','K','A'] #A=14, K=13, Q=12, J=11, T=10
colour = ['C','D','H','S'] #clubs, diamonds, hearts, spades
hands = ['high card','pair','two pair','three of kind','straight','flush','full house','four of kind','straight flush'] #royal flush is not included, since it's a special case of a straight flush

#extracts the file
def fileloc(name,extension):
    cur_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    with open(os.path.join(cur_path,'..',name+extension),newline=None) as inputfile:
        document = inputfile.read()
    return document

#function to flatten the list and get a tuple
def flatten(l):
  out = []
  for item in l:
    if isinstance(item, (list, tuple)):
      out.extend(flatten(item))
    else:
      out.append(item)
  return out

#function to determine the winning hand
def winninghand(hand):
    #gets a specific hand of player 1 and of player 2
    player1hand = player1_games[hand]
    player2hand = player2_games[hand]
    #valuelist1 will be an ordered list (high - low) of card values of player 1, valuelist2 of player2
    valuelist1 = []
    valuelist2 = []
    #defining winner variable
    winner = -1
    for i in range(5):
        valuelist1.append(player1hand[i][0])
        valuelist2.append(player2hand[i][0])

    #gives a value to T,J,Q,K,A
    valuelist1= [x.replace('T','10').replace('J','11').replace('Q','12').replace('K','13').replace('A','14') for x in valuelist1]
    valuelist2= [x.replace('T','10').replace('J','11').replace('Q','12').replace('K','13').replace('A','14') for x in valuelist2]
    valuelist1 = [int(i) for i in valuelist1]
    valuelist2 = [int(i) for i in valuelist2]
    valuelist1 = sorted(valuelist1,reverse=True)
    valuelist2 = sorted(valuelist2,reverse=True)

    player1value = valuechecker(player1hand,valuelist1)
    player2value = valuechecker(player2hand,valuelist2)

    #winner = 1 means player 1 won, winner = 0 means player 2 wins
    #first checks if hand value is greater for player 1 or 2
    #if it is a draw, it goes past each card value to see who has got the better hand
    if player1value[0] > player2value[0]:
        winner = 1
    elif player2value[0] > player1value[0]:
        winner = 0
    elif player1value[0] == player2value[0]:
        if player1value[1] > player2value[1]:
            winner = 1
        elif player1value[1] < player2value[1]:
            winner = 0
        elif player1value[1] == player2value[1]:
            if player1value[2] > player2value[2]:
                winner = 1
            elif player1value[2] < player2value[2]:
                winner = 0
            elif player1value[2] == player2value[2]:
                if player1value[3] > player2value[3]:
                    winner = 1
                elif player1value[3] < player2value[3]:
                    winner = 0
                elif player1value[3] == player2value[3]:
                    if player1value[4] > player2value[4]:
                        winner = 1
                    elif player1value[4] < player2value[4]:
                        winner = 0
                    elif player1value[4] == player2value[4]:
                        #it was defined in the problem statement that there would always be one winner.
                        raise ValueError("There should be a winner") 

    return winner

#checking the value of a hand
def valuechecker(list,vallist):
    #variables for
    #occs : occurrences of cards
    #mostcommonfreq : amount of occurrences of highest occuring card value
    #nextcommonfreq : amount of occurrences of second highest occuring card value
    #mostcommon : highest occurring card value
    #nextcommon : second highest occurring card value
    #colourtest : checks if all colours are the same
    #consectest : checks if numbers are consecutive
    occs = maxoccurences(vallist)
    mostcommonfreq = occs[0][1]
    nextcommonfreq = occs[1][1]
    mostcommon = occs[0][0]
    nextcommon = occs[1][0]
    colourtest = samecolour(list)
    consectest = consecutive(vallist)

    #check flush
    if colourtest==True and consectest==False:
        val = [hands.index('flush')] + [i for i in vallist]

    #check straight
    elif colourtest==False and consectest==True:
        maximum = max(vallist)
        minimum = min(vallist)
        if maximum==14 and minimum == 2:
            val = [hands.index('straight')] + [i for i in vallist]
            val.remove(14)
            val = vals.append(1)
        else:
            val = [hands.index('straight')] + [i for i in vallist]

    #check straight flush
    elif colourtest==True and consectest==True:
        val = [hands.index('straight flush')] + [i for i in vallist]

    #check pair
    elif(mostcommonfreq == 2 and nextcommonfreq != 2):
        vallist.remove(mostcommon)
        vallist.remove(mostcommon)
        vallist.insert(0,mostcommon)
        vallist.insert(0,mostcommon)
        val = [hands.index('pair')] + [i for i in vallist]

    #check 2 pair
    elif(mostcommonfreq == 2 and nextcommonfreq == 2):
        vallist.remove(mostcommon)
        vallist.remove(mostcommon)
        vallist.remove(nextcommon)
        vallist.remove(nextcommon)
        if mostcommon>nextcommon:
            vallist.insert(0,nextcommon)
            vallist.insert(0,nextcommon)
            vallist.insert(0,mostcommon)
            vallist.insert(0,mostcommon)
        else:
            vallist.insert(0,mostcommon)
            vallist.insert(0,mostcommon)
            vallist.insert(0,nextcommon)
            vallist.insert(0,nextcommon)
        val = [hands.index('two pair')] + [i for i in vallist]

    #check 3 of kind
    elif(mostcommonfreq == 3 and nextcommonfreq != 2):
        vallist.remove(mostcommon)
        vallist.remove(mostcommon)
        vallist.remove(mostcommon)
        vallist.insert(0,mostcommon)
        vallist.insert(0,mostcommon)
        vallist.insert(0,mostcommon)
        val = [hands.index('three of kind')] + [i for i in vallist]

    #check full house
    elif(mostcommonfreq == 3 and nextcommonfreq == 2):
        vallist.remove(nextcommon)
        vallist.remove(nextcommon)
        vallist.append(nextcommon)
        vallist.append(nextcommon)
        val = [hands.index('full house')] + [i for i in vallist]

    #check 4 of kind
    elif(mostcommonfreq == 4):
        vallist.remove(mostcommon)
        vallist.remove(mostcommon)
        vallist.remove(mostcommon)
        vallist.remove(mostcommon)
        vallist.insert(0,mostcommon)
        vallist.insert(0,mostcommon)
        vallist.insert(0,mostcommon)
        vallist.insert(0,mostcommon)        
        val = [hands.index('four of kind')] + [i for i in vallist]

    #check high card
    elif  vallist[0] != vallist[1] != vallist[2] != vallist[3] != vallist[4]:
        val = [hands.index('high card')]+[i for i in vallist]

    return val

#checking whether a hand is a straight -- checking to see if the numbers are in consecutive order
def consecutive(vallist):
    #takes the max and min value of the hand, this is used to check whether it has an Ace, for bottom or top straight
    maxim = max(vallist)
    minim = min(vallist)
    #if max is Ace, and min is 2, then perhaps it is a bottom straight, check first
    if maxim == 14 and minim==2:
        vallist.remove(14)
        vallist.append(1)
        if (vallist[0]==vallist[1]+1==vallist[2]+2==vallist[3]+3==vallist[4]+4):
            return True
        else: 
            #making sure the list is restored to its original state
            vallist.remove(1)
            vallist.insert(0,14)
            return False
    elif (vallist[0]==vallist[1]+1==vallist[2]+2==vallist[3]+3==vallist[4]+4):
            return True 
    else: return False

#checking whether a hand is a flush -- checking to see if the suits are the same
def samecolour(list):
    if list[0][1] == list[1][1] == list[2][1] == list[3][1] == list[4][1]:
        return True
    else: return False

#checking how often a certain card value appears
#used to check for pair, 2 pair, 3 of kind, full house, 4 of kind
def maxoccurences(vallist):
    occu = Counter(vallist).most_common(2)
    return occu


#importing the file with all pokerhands, and turning it into a list with which can be worked
s= time()
gamesPlayed = []
document =  fileloc('poker','.txt')
document = document.replace(' ','').replace('\n','').replace('\r','')
for line in document:
    gamesPlayed.append(line.split(','))

#each character is its own list, so I make a tuple in a list, where each tuple describes a card
gamesPlayed = list(zip(*[iter(flatten(gamesPlayed))]*2))

player1_games = []
startwindow1 = 0
endwindow1 = 5

#extracting only the hands that player 1 had
while endwindow1 <= len(gamesPlayed):
    handList = []
    if endwindow1 > len(gamesPlayed): break
    else: 
        player1_games.append(gamesPlayed[startwindow1:endwindow1])
        startwindow1 += 10
        endwindow1 += 10

player2_games = []
startwindow2 = 5
endwindow2 = 10

#extracting only the hands that player 2 had
while endwindow2 <= len(gamesPlayed):
    handList = []
    if endwindow2 > len(gamesPlayed): break
    else: 
        player2_games.append(gamesPlayed[startwindow2:endwindow2])
        startwindow2 += 10
        endwindow2 += 10

#how many games did player 1 and player 2 win
player1_wins = 0
player2_wins = 0    
totalgames = len(player1_games)

for i in range(len(player1_games)):
    if winninghand(i) == 1:
        player1_wins += 1
    elif winninghand(i) == 0:
        player2_wins += 1

print(player1_wins,player2_wins, time()-s)
```

Comment: See [this answer](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/95075/11728) for some ways to reduce the amount of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A partial answer:

In your function `winninghand`, you can replace the long lines of nested ifs with:

```
def comparehands(player1value,player2value):
    for p1, p2 in zip(sorted(player1value, reverse=True), sorted(player2value, reverse=True)):
        if p1 == p2:
            continue
        return p1 > p2
    raise ValueError("There should be a winner")
```

This will also return 1 if player 1 wins and 0 if player 2 wins.

---

For constants it is customary to use ALL_CAPS:

```
CARDS = ['2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','T','J','Q','K','A']
COLOUR = ['C','D','H','S']
```

Instead of building a valuelist with fancy replaces use the fact that you already defined an order in CARDS:

```
player1values = [CARDS.index(card[0]) for card in player1_games[hand]]
player2values = [CARDS.index(card[0]) for card in player2_games[hand]]
```

This allows you to compactify the function winninghand greatly:

```
def get_values(playerhand):
    return sorted([CARDS.index(card[0]) for card in playerhand], reverse=True)

def winninghand(hand):
    playerhands = (player1_games[hand], player2_games[hand])
    p1values, p2values = map(get_values, playerhands)
    for p1, p2 in zip(p1values, p2values):
        if p1 == p2:
            continue
        return p1 > p2
    raise ValueError("There should be a winner")
```

The part of calling `valuechecker` is still missing in there.

---

You should almost never use this:

```
if colourtest==True and consectest==False:
    val = [hands.index('flush')] + [i for i in vallist]
```

Instead use the fact that colourtest and consectest are already boolean:

```
if colourtest and not consectest:
    # Do stuff
```

---

I would nest these ifs somewhat:

```
#check straight flush, flush and straight
if colourtest:
    if consectest:
        # straight flush
    else:
        # flush
elif consectest:
    # straight
```

---

In `samecolour`:

```
def samecolour(list):
    return len(set(card[1] for card in list)) == 1
```

---

In the original samecolour, as well as in other places, you are using this as the last line in your function:

```
else: return False
```

Just use `return False`, because if you get to that line, False is the only option left