# Poker hand valuator in Python

Tags: python, numpy, playing-cards

As you will probably notice very quickly from the code below, I'm not very experienced coder. Below is my attempt at valuating poker hands in Python. The code below may not be pretty but it seems to be doing the job. And it seems to be quick enough to evaluate ranges on flop and turn. The output allows for easy comparison of hands (on my to do list next).

Please kindly review my code and let me know if there are any obvious ways to make it quicker and easier to read? Any hints will be highly appreciated.

```
import numpy, random

#Poker hand is ordered in form of a "punchcard". Rows are colors.
#Order in a row is from 2 to A

#Card array [[2s,3s,4s,5s,6s,7s,8s,9s,Ts,Js,Qs,Ks,As], 
#            [2h,3h,4h,5h,6h,7h,8h,9h,Th,Jh,Qh,Kh,Ah], 
#            [2c,3c,4c,5c,6c,7c,8c,9c,Tc,Jc,Qc,Kc,Ac],  
#            [2d,3d,4d,5d,6d,7d,8d,9d,Td,Jd,Qd,Kd,Ad]]

#Deck for testing 
deck = ["2s", "3s", "4s", "5s", "6s", "7s", "8s", "9s", "Ts", "Js", "Qs", "Ks", "As",
        "2h", "3h", "4h", "5h", "6h", "7h", "8h", "9h", "Th", "Jh", "Qh", "Kh", "Ah",
        "2c", "3c", "4c", "5c", "6c", "7c", "8c", "9c", "Tc", "Jc", "Qc", "Kc", "Ac",
        "2d", "3d", "4d", "5d", "6d", "7d", "8d", "9d", "Td", "Jd", "Qd", "Kd", "Ad",
]

#Function generating 1000 7 card hands to test
def thousandHands(deck):
    allTheHands = []
    for i in range(1000):
        random.shuffle(deck)
        allTheHands.append(deck[:7])
    return allTheHands

#Hand Encoder takes a list of strings and translates it to a matrix
def HandEncoder(card_list):
   
    poker_hand = [ [ 0 for i in range(13) ] for j in range(4) ]

    card_dict = {
        "2s": [[0],[0]], "2h": [[1],[0]], "2c": [[2],[0]], "2d": [[3],[0]],
        "3s": [[0],[1]], "3h": [[1],[1]], "3c": [[2],[1]], "3d": [[3],[1]],
        "4s": [[0],[2]], "4h": [[1],[2]], "4c": [[2],[2]], "4d": [[3],[2]],
        "5s": [[0],[3]], "5h": [[1],[3]], "5c": [[2],[3]], "5d": [[3],[3]],
        "6s": [[0],[4]], "6h": [[1],[4]], "6c": [[2],[4]], "6d": [[3],[4]],
        "7s": [[0],[5]], "7h": [[1],[5]], "7c": [[2],[5]], "7d": [[3],[5]],
        "8s": [[0],[6]], "8h": [[1],[6]], "8c": [[2],[6]], "8d": [[3],[6]],
        "9s": [[0],[7]], "9h": [[1],[7]], "9c": [[2],[7]], "9d": [[3],[7]],
        "Ts": [[0],[8]], "Th": [[1],[8]], "Tc": [[2],[8]], "Td": [[3],[8]],
        "Js": [[0],[9]], "Jh": [[1],[9]], "Jc": [[2],[9]], "Jd": [[3],[9]], 
        "Qs": [[0],[10]],"Qh": [[1],[10]],"Qc": [[2],[10]],"Qd": [[3],[10]],
        "Ks": [[0],[11]],"Kh": [[1],[11]],"Kc": [[2],[11]],"Kd": [[3],[11]],
        "As": [[0],[12]],"Ah": [[1],[12]],"Ac": [[2],[12]],"Ad": [[3],[12]],
    }
    for card in card_list:
        i = card_dict.get(card)[0].pop()
        j = card_dict.get(card)[1].pop()
        poker_hand[i][j] = 1
    return poker_hand

#Hand valuation function
def ValuePokerHand(PokerHand):

    handArray = numpy.array(PokerHand)

    #list of sums of cards with given face value
    face_values = numpy.sum(handArray, axis=0)

    #function to check for consecutive five cards in a range
    def checkForStraight(inputArray):
        result = [False, 0]
        for card_i in range(13, 4, -1):
            if numpy.all(inputArray[card_i-5:card_i]):
                result = [True, card_i-1]
                break
            elif numpy.all(inputArray[0:4]) and inputArray[12] >= 1:
                result = [True, 3]
        return result

    #Step 1 - check for Straight flush and if present return the index of highest card
    for color in handArray:
        if checkForStraight(color)[0]:
            result = ["Straight Flush"] + [checkForStraight(color)[1]]
            return result
    
    #Step 2 - check for quads and return index of quads and index of kicker
    if numpy.amax(face_values) == 4:
        quad_index = numpy.argmax(face_values)
        kicker_index = 0
        for kicker in range(12, 0, -1):
            if 4 > face_values[kicker] > 0:
                kicker_index = kicker
                break    
        return ["Quads", quad_index, kicker_index]

    #Step 3 - check for full house and return indexex of trips and pair
    if numpy.sort(face_values)[12] == 3 and numpy.sort(face_values)[11] >=2:
        trips_index = 0
        pair_index = 0

        for trips in range (12, 0, -1):
            if face_values[trips] == 3:
                trips_index = trips
                break
        for pair in range (12, 0, -1):
            if pair != trips_index:
                if face_values[pair] >=2:
                    pair_index = pair
                    break
        return ["Full House", trips_index, pair_index]
    
    #Step 4 - check for Flush and return index of the highest card in sequence
    for color in handArray:
        if numpy.sum(color) >= 5:
            result = ["Flush"]
            for card in range (12, -1, -1):
                if color[card] > 0:
                    result.append(card)
            return result[:6]

    #Step 5 - Check for Straight and return the index of highest card in sequence
    if checkForStraight(face_values)[0]:
        return ["Straight"] + [checkForStraight(face_values)[1]]

    #Step 6 - Check for trips and return indices of trips and two highest kickers
    if numpy.sort(face_values)[12] == 3:
        trips_index = numpy.argmax(face_values)
        first_kicker = 0
        second_kicker = 0
        for card_i in range(12, 0, -1):
            if 3 > face_values[card_i] > 0:
                first_kicker = card_i
                break
        for card_j in range(first_kicker - 1, 0, -1):
            if 3 > face_values[card_j] > 0:
                second_kicker = card_j
                break
        return ["Trips", trips_index, first_kicker, second_kicker]
    
    #Step 7 - Check for 2 pairs and return indices of both pairs and a kicker
    if numpy.sort(face_values)[12] == 2 and numpy.sort(face_values)[11] >=2:
        first_pair = 0
        second_pair = 0
        kicker = 0

        for pair1 in range (12, 0, -1):
            if face_values[pair1] == 2:
                first_pair = pair1
                break
        for pair2 in range (12, 0, -1):
            if pair2 != first_pair:
                if face_values[pair2] ==2:
                    second_pair = pair2
                    break
        for card in range (12, 0, -1):
            if card != first_pair and card != second_pair:
                if face_values[card] > 0:
                    kicker = card
        return ["Two Pairs", first_pair, second_pair, kicker]
    
    #Step 8 - Check for pair and retuns indices of a pair and 3 highest kickers
    if numpy.sort(face_values)[12] == 2:
        pair_index = 0
        kickers = []
        for card in range (12, 0, -1):
            if face_values[card] == 2:
                pair_index = card
                break
        for kicker in range (12, 0, -1):
            if face_values[kicker] > 0 and kicker != pair_index:
                kickers.append(kicker)
        kicker1, kicker2, kicker3 = kickers[0:3]
            
        return ["Pair", pair_index, kicker1, kicker2, kicker3]

    #Step 9 - High Card, returns list of indices of top 5 cards
    res = ["High Card"]    
    for card in range(12, -1,- 1):
        if face_values[card] > 0:
            res.append(card)
    
    return res[:6]

handsList = thousandHands(deck)

#function comparing list of hands and returning the highest one
def compareHands(listOfHands):
    pass

for hand in handsList:
    print(hand, ValuePokerHand(HandEncoder(hand)))
```

Comment: [See this answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/95075/11728) for an approach based on conversion to canonical form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few comments about your code:

## Bug

Your code works mostly fine, but fails to identify an ace-low straigh (`A 2 3 4 5`).

## Testing

To test your code, you try to run it with 1000 random hands. While this may be useful to check if your code runs at all and behaves *mostly* as expected, it is not a good enough approach, as illustrated by the bug I pointed out.

The odds of a random hand having this specific straight is quite low, and identifying visually it in a 1000-line printout is next to impossible.

You should define specific and reproducible test-cases, trying to cover all cases.

Using a testing framework like [`unittest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html) is also highly recommended.

## Code layout

Given the functionality provided by your code, I assume it's intended for use as part of a bigger program, perhaps a poker simulating game, or a training application.

It should also be able to be used by your test runner.

In both case, you should lay out your code like a module, allowing to `import HandValuator` in another file. This implies removing all statements outside of the scope of functions, or putting them behind a `if __name__ == '__main__` guard, and removing functions that wouldn't be useful outside of your module (such as `thousandHands`) or hiding them by prefixing their name with an underscore (`_`).

Try to figure out what API you want to expose. If I were to reuse your code, I would probably want to simply call `ValuePokerHand(hand)`, not `ValuePokerHand(HandEncoder(hand)))`, and as such `HandEncoder` should probably called from inside `ValuePokerHand` and "hidden" from the caller.

## Style

As noted in another answer, you should follow style conventions recommended by [PEP-8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/), including naming conventions, `import`s on separate lines, white space usage...

This would make your code more consistent for everyone (including your future self) familiar with Python, and as such easier to work with and review.

## Documentation and comments

You document your functions and module using comments, which is better than nothing, but these would better be [docstrings](https://peps.python.org/pep-0257/) and be included after the functions' signatures (or at the beginning of the module).

Otherwise, your use of comments is pretty good.

## Naming

Functions and method are better described by a verb than a noun. As such, `ValuePokerHand` would be better named `evaluate_poker_hand`, or `HandEncoder` as `encode_hand`

## Logic

If find your logic hard to follow, for example I can't wrap my head around your use of an array of flags for the full deck, as encoded by the `HandEncoder`. I feel like the logic could be simplified by working with arrays of cards.

## Use appropriate types/classes

You mention that "The output allows for easy comparison of hands". I disagree, what you have are arrays of mixed `string`s and `int`s of varying length, and comparing them isn't going to be trivial.

If no builtin type is a good match for your data, classes are a useful thing to implement, and will make working with them much easier down the line.

Another option would be to evaluate hands to a numerical value, which will be trivially compared down the line.

Answer (score 0):

[PEP-8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/) - specifically [naming conventions](https://realpython.com/python-pep8/#naming-styles). For variables and functions you should prefer snake_case over camel_case and PascalCase for classes.

Also functions generally *do* things and variables/classes represent things so you should name them as such. Functions should be named as *verbs* for readability. For example `generate_hands(num_hands=1000, cards_per_hand=7)` and `def encode_hand(card_list)`.